# Arduino Data Logger Shield is incompatible with many devices

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensors, i2c

I got a Data Logger Shield [like this](https://www.amazon.de/AZDelivery-DatenLogger-Data-Recorder-Logger/dp/B01NATCT7N/) for my Arduino. It works like intended most of the time, but I recognized that it is incompatible with many other devices for an Arduino. For example the small 0.96 inch I2C OLED displays [like these](https://www.amazon.de/AZDelivery-Display-Arduino-Raspberry-gratis/dp/B074N9VLZX/) or an analog hygrometer module (a sensor for measuring soil moisture) [like this](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07V6M5C4H/). All libraries are updated.
The displays are simply not showing anything and the Arduino does not get any input from the sensor with the shield on, without both devices work just fine.

Maybe my Arduino or the Data Logger Shield is faulty, I can't rule that out, but I know from a friend that encountered similar problems.
It also could be, that the shield just blocks certain data channels or similar, that I just know nothing about.

I would be grateful for a solution, as this stops my latest project from continuing as planned.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried decupling the realtimeclock via hardware sepparation? This could solve problems with the I²C Interface.[image: Shematic cutline]

Comment: Having many devices on the I2C bus shouldn't be a problem though - that's what it's made for.

Comment: Cutting this probably works, but then the RTC is permanently damaged. So no solution if I want to use it. I now use the Arduino ethernet shield to log the data. I might try to use a other RTC in combination in the future, I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one Interface at the time, In the past I had problems using SPI(SD-Card) and I²C(RTC) at the same time. Either use only one, or alternate between usages.
The problem seems to originate from the limited timers of the Arduino, when comunicating presice timing is needed for both Interfaces, and the two Interfaces in Paralell use too much resources for the little Arduino to handle.